# PETSc and MPI COMM world proper usage

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Hi I have a program written in C++ in which one or two functions out of many are using PETSc.

When I'm calling these functions which would be the proper approach while using PETSc

```
1) a)change all MPI_COMM_WORLD to PETSC_COMM_WORLD for my entire program
   b)change MPI_Init to PetscInitialize
```

..

2) create a separate comm world for petsc and pass that on to the function

```
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    ..
    //some many line of code
    ..

    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, 0, &PETSC_COMM_WORLD);

    petsc_function(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,.....

    //some how reverting the comm_split here to continue as normal so all the non petsc functions work
```

..

3) or can i simply get by just using MPI_COMM_WORLD with the Petsc function
..

4) or is there another approach I am unaware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `PetscInitialize` first. You can replace the call to `MPI_Init` with it.

There is no need to set `PETSC_COMM_WORLD` unless you only want to use PETSc on a subset of the ranks.  If you do not set `PETSC_COMM_WORLD` yourself, it will be set automatically by `PetscInitialize` to be a copy of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Then, when you call PETSc functions you can use `PETSC_COMM_WORLD`.  At the end of the program call `PetscFinalize`, which will call `MPI_Finalize` for you unless you called `MPI_Init` manually instead of using `PetscInitialize` alone.

There is no need to change `MPI_COMM_WORLD` to `PETSC_COMM_WORLD` in the rest of the program.

Comment: thank you very much, the documentation is a little confusing when first starting out